# Elasticsearch query for values that exist in multiple geo locations

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, geolocation

I have an index with documents that look like the following:

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "location: { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [3.295, 6.673]}
}
```

I can do a geo-polygon query no problem.  But now I want to search two geo-polygons and have it return only those documents that have the same "name" value in both.  So if "name":"Jason Smith" exists in both geo-polygons, then those documents will be returned.  But if "Jason Smith" only exists in one, then it will not be returned.  I can't figure out how to write this query, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the query I am working with now:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":{
                "bool":{
                    "should":[
                        {"geo_distance": {"coordinates":[32.4809, 12.0422],"distance": "100 m"}},
                        {"geo_distance": {"coordinates":[33.4827, 13.0438],"distance": "100 m"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "found":{
            "terms":{
                "field": "name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried both "must" and "should". Must will only return documents that have a lat/lng coordinate in both areas, and Should returns all documents from both areas.  I need the query to return documents that have the same "name" in both areas, not coordinate.

Comment: Please join an example of your querry. Seems you are making a AND (bool) instead of OR.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the query I am working with.

Comment: Please try by changing coordinatesformat "coordinates": {
                  "lat": 32.4809,
                  "lon": 12.0422
                },

Comment: I tried on my side, got not issue at all with similar data. Maybe post your full querry with the name filter.

Comment: that's where I'm stuck. I can get documents back from each location/area, but I don't know how to filter that to only return documents that have the same name/value in both locations/area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i edited. Should work we agg by name, then by zone using one of the aera requested. After we post filter aggregation using bucket_selector, _bucket_count gets the array size of the subaggeo aggregates, and so if his size is == 2, name is on both aera. Please tell me if it s work ;)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "coordinates": {
                  "lat": 48.858837,
                  "lon": 2.27702
                },
                "distance": "10km"
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "coordinates": {
                  "lat": 40.697149,
                  "lon": -74.2598
                },
                "distance": "10km"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "found": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subagggeo": {
          "geo_distance": {
            "field": "coordinates",
            "origin": "48.858837, 2.27702",
            "unit": "m",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": 10000
              },
              {
                "from": 10001
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "min_bucket_selector": {
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "hits": "subagggeo._bucket_count"
        },
        "script": {
          "inline": "params.hits > 1"
        }
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This query is searching for a specific name or value.  what I'm trying to do is get  all the values that exist in both areas.

Comment: Ok sorry, Misunderstood, will try on monday. I thinck you have to use sub aggregations.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I think it's working.  Can you explain what is happening in the sub aggregation portion?

Comment: Aggs are like a groupby, the first one (found) group by name. You got an array (buckets) of "Key = name", "doc_count" = occurance. You can add sub aggregations inside to get other information for each of them. In my exemple, for each name, i want to know how many of them are < to 10km to my geopoints and how many are >. So i got for each name subaggregation (a geo_distance one) with Buckets, spliting the documents according to their distance. The last part, the bucker selector one is a "post filter for aggregation result", here i indicate to work on geo_distance aggr

Comment: and keep only those with documents found < 10000 and > 10000, so with name on the 2 parts. _bucket_count = size of the array.

Comment: Ok I see. So you're moving the area to check to encompass both geopoints and check that the names returned from the first agg exists.  But what if the two original geopoints are farther apart or even opposite ends of the globe?

Comment: If they are very far away no pb, this work, the sub geo_distance agg will split document according to the area you set (just pick one of them). If both area have inclusion not null, yeah could have a problem, but it should be easy to adapt the querry and maybe add a second geo_distance agg at the same level and  bucket_selector the result of each one.